# how to recover deleted Photo EXIF

Tags: exif

Apparently cropping or uploading photos to some certain Websites deletes its metadata.
I have a bunch of photos which have been cropped and then uploaded to [telegram](https://telegram.org) and so far I know that both cropping and uploading, deletes metadata of the file.
Is there any way to recover the deleted data?

Comment: If you do not have the original files then no, you can't recover the metadate.

Comment: unless you ever had the photo with exif data on your harddrive or on a usb stick that you could recover with `photorec`, no. The data has been removed from the file

Comment: For next time: use an editor that can preserve EXIF data in JPEG files, such as IrfanView.